# saving selected data in cookie failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some dropdowns to choose between a few dates. The issue is that after choosing the date, the user needs to log in. After that, all the session of member date refreshing the choosing date lost (is not only the js, a lot of date coming because of the relevant choosing.

I tried to save the selected item in a cookie, but it didn't work.

I have the session of the index

```
private int getIndexFromSession()
{
    int index = 0;
    if (Session["DTF_selectedIndex"] != null)
    {
        index = (int)Session["DTF_selectedIndex"];
        // Session.Remove("DTF_selectedIndex");
        if (index > dateTimeFilter.Items.Count)
            index = 0;
    }
    return index;
}
```

the drop down in .aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dateTimeFilter" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="dateTimeFilter_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

and .cs

```
protected void dateTimeFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //   showsDatalistPanel.Visible = true;
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

    if (ddl.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        Session["DTF_selectedIndex"] = ddl.SelectedValue;
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("DTF_selectedIndex", ddl.SelectedValue);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        cookie.Expires = now.AddMinutes(10);

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

and the request

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (Session["DTF_selectedIndex"] != null)
    {
        Session["DTF_selectedIndex"] = Request.Cookies["DTF_selectedIndex"];       
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting the session value only if it's not already null. So if it hasn't already been set you'll never set it. Try assigning the cookie to a variable and inspecting it in the debugger, or just set a breakpoint and enter `?Request.Cookies["DTF_selectedIndex"]` in the immediate window. Otherwise it's unclear whether the cookie isn't really in the request or the session value just isn't getting set.

Comment: Did you debug the code? In `Page_Load` you are checking `if(Session["DTF_selectedIndex"] != null)` that means it will never set value of session if the session value is null. Did you try changing it to `if(Session["DTF_selectedIndex"] == null)` in `Page_Load` ?

Comment: @ScottHannen thank you. the issue that I have the data I need in the cookie. But can't get to it/ while requesting it  I have the  problem. all I need to get the same date, in the same page after refreshing the page while sign in